# Reading GeoJSON Data in GeoPandas: "Failed to read GeoJSON data"

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, geopandas

**Trouble Reading GeoJSON Data in GeoPandas: "Failed to read GeoJSON data**"

I am facing an issue while trying to read a GeoJSON file using the geopandas library. Whenever I attempt to load the GeoJSON file into my Jupyter Notebook, I encounter the error message: "Failed to read GeoJSON data." Despite trying several troubleshooting steps, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. I'm seeking assistance to diagnose and fix this problem.

I'm trying to read a GeoJSON file using the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
file_path = "C:\\Users\\PERSONAL\\Desktop\\GIS\\Canada_Data\\Canada_provinces_2.geojson"
try:
provinces = gpd.read_file(file_path)
provinces = provinces.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
except Exception as e:
  print("An error occurred:", e)
```

The code execution produces the following error message:

```
An error occurred: Failed to read GeoJSON data
```

I have attempted the following steps to troubleshoot the issue without success:

Checked the file path and verified the file's existence.

Ensured that the GeoJSON file is valid by opening it in a text editor.

Confirmed that I have GDAL 3.6.2 installed.

Created a new virtual environment and installed only necessary packages (geopandas, GDAL, Fiona).

Uninstalled and reinstalled geopandas, GDAL, and Fiona.

Tried reading a different GeoJSON file to eliminate the possibility of a corrupted file.

Below are my system recommendations:

Operating System: [Windows 10]

Python Version: [Python Version: 3.9.17 (main, Jul  5 2023, 20:47:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]

GDAL Version: 3.6.2

What might be causing this issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: "*Ensured that the GeoJSON file is valid by opening it in a text editor.*" - A text editor won't tell you if it's valid. Try a GeoJSON validator like https://geojson.io or https://geojsonlint.com

Comment: You don't say where you got / how you generated the geojson, but the provinces geojson from [here](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-canada-province%40public/export/?disjunctive.prov_name_en) works for me in geopandas.